# spl_autoload_register() throws a undefined constant notice

Tags: php, function, constants

I might have set this code up wrong, but it works perfectly when `error_reporting` is set to `E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE`.

```
function load_fw_phpClass($fw_phpClass_name){
    $fw_class_file=path_to_classes.$fw_phpClass_name.'.class.php';
    file_exists($fw_class_file)?include $fw_class_file:null;
}   spl_autoload_register(load_fw_phpClass);
```

`path_to_classes` is a personally defined constant.

I changed the `error_reporting` to `E_ALL` just to check if there was any notices - and yes there was (2 for the same reasons on different lines):
`**Notice:** Use of undefined constant load_fw_phpClass - assumed 'load_fw_phpClass' in ...`.

It looks like the `spl_autoload_register();`-function is treating the function-name as a constant and telling me that it has not been defined yet - which is not a suprise since it for one; it's not a constant - and second; it should only be excecuted when there is need for a class... I mean; Isn't that the reason to use the `spl_autoload_register();`-function?

Anyway; Anyone else experienced this "error"? and know of a way to handle this?
Would be much appreciated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the name of the function (the string):

```
 spl_autoload_register('load_fw_phpClass');
```

Comment: oh, that was kind of embarrassing. And what do you know - php.net says the same in their examples. Bad reading on my part...  Thanks for quick reply though...